# Chatbot messages do not show up in Facebook Messenger chat heads

Tags: node.js, notifications, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger

I am developing a chatbot for Facebook Messenger using Microsoft Bot Framework. The bot sends the user proactive messages (reminders). Unfortunately, for some reason the messages never show up in a chat head (the Android widget for conversations), nor pop up a chat head if it wasn't present on the screen before. It does happen for other chatbots ([Jarvis](https://www.facebook.com/helloimjarvis/), for example).

This is the code that sends the reminders:

```
Reminder.find({ next_reminder: { $lte: new Date() } }, (err, res) => {
        if (err !== null) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        res.forEach(reminder => {
            // Build a notification message and address it to user who created the reminder           

            const msg = new builder.Message().text('...');

            bot.beginDialog(reminder.user_address, '*:/sendReminder', {message: msg, nudnik: nudnik});

            });
        });
    };
};
```

I have also tried `bot.send(msg, () => ....)` and `session.beginDialog('sendReminder', msg)`. However, there is still no indication from Messenger when the message is received. What could go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out! Apparently, the default notification setting for a Facebook message is not to show a notification. To change it, in NodeJS you should add channel-specific data to the message with the following code:

```
msg = msg.sourceEvent({
                    facebook:
                        {notification_type: 'REGULAR'}
                });
```

You can discover more in official documentation by Microsoft ([here](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)) and also in [this Github discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3714).